# Does metamask uses web3?

Tags: web3js, ether, metamask, wallets

I was curious if metamask uses web3 for communication with eth node ? I tried google for it; showed bunch of other results but didn't precisely answered my question.
 Indepth answer on how metamask works in addition to my question would be just cherry on the top.
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MetaMask does use Web3.js internally. You can check it in the source code on [GitHub](https://github.com/MetaMask/metamask-extension). Previously, MetaMask would also inject `window.web3` in the current page, but [that was changed to only inject `window.ethereum` instead](https://medium.com/metamask/breaking-changes-to-the-metamask-inpage-provider-b4dde069dd0a). Dapps can use `window.ethereum` for safe interaction with a user's wallet.